# How do I make Tomcat route API requests via specific IP addresses in the same machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat

I have multiple public IPs associated with my EC2 instance in which a tomcat server is running. Now I want to be able to choose which IP address to route my API requests to. For example, if I encounter scenario A, route API call via IP address 1, scenario B via IP address 2 etc. Is there a way to do this? My instance has a secondary ENI attached.

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is that a particular airline wants a different IP to be whitelisted for each client we service although the API is the same. The only solution which I can think of is provisioning a different proxy server for each client and whitelisting the IP address for each of those proxy servers. However, it is not very cost effective.

Comment: If Tomcat is running on the machine with all the IP addresses attached, then by the time Tomcat gets the API request it is too late to pick which IP address the request should have been routed on, it's already been routed through one of them. Please provide more information about the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @MarkB I've added more details about what I'm trying to solve.